# JQuery Date range picker calendar with variable weeks

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I would like to implement a weekly date range picker in jquery similar to this image[image]

The only implementation that i can see of this is using mobiscroll plugin which is not free and i would prefer another way to do this using jquery or javascript or any free tool out there.

Any one has other ideas or solutions on how to achieve this using any other datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

You may try using **ranges** option with daterange picker where you need to build you custom **ranges** like shown here...

```
$('#datepicker').daterangepicker({
    "showWeekNumbers": true,
    ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), 
        moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    "startDate": "12/26/2018",
    "endDate": "01/01/2019"
}, function(start, end, label) {
    //
});
```

for more reference please visit
    [Date Range Piker Examples](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples)